# DateTime.Now Throw exception in SQL saying it's not valid datetime value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET and I need your expert help to solve this. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 and SQL Server. I try to insert some data to database using SQL this is my query

```
INSERT INTO tem (Telephone, Status, CreateDate) 
VALUES ('" + telephone + "','"+ status +"','" + DateTime.Now + "');
```

It's working fine in localhost but after I deploy to server it showing an error message:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

My `DateTime.Now` value is like `28/02/2016 8:45:45 AM`.

If I add 2016-02-28 8:45:45 AM by hard-coding then it's working.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Appreciate your comment. It was parametrized and I change it while i'm testing. Any suggestions on my problem.

Comment: Well, the suggestion is: **use parameters!** Those will not only solve your SQL injection vulnerability, using parameters properly will also fix your "formatting a date as a string" problem (since you don't need to format your date as a string anymore - you pass it in as a **native** `DateTime` value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **parametrized queries** that solve both your SQL injection vulnerability, and also avoid having to convert your `DateTime` to a string which often leads to problems.

Use code something like this:

```
// define connection string and **PARAMETRIZED** insert query 
string connectionStirng = ".....";
string insertQry = "INSERT INTO tem (Telephone, Status, CreateDate) VALUES (@Telephone, @Status, @CreateDate);";

// set up connection and command in using blocks
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQry, conn))
{
    // define the parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telephone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = telephone;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = status;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreateDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

    // open connection, execute query, close connection
    conn.Open();
    int rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support marc_s. In the testing environment this code working fine but after I deploy it showing this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". SqlConnection object is not creating.

Comment: @wajira000: check your configs - typically, the connection string is defined in a config file - do you have your config file in place? Is the connection string missing from it, or named differently?

Comment: Thanks marc_s. It was the problem now it's working fine. Is there any tool or method that I can use to debug some situation like that. I have access to the server.Because when it's in production hard to track the bugs like this.

Answer (score 2):

as @marc_s says in first comment, you shouldn't use SQL statement, instead of your code, do something like this:

```
conn2 = new SqlConnection();
        conn2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connSpionshopString"].ConnectionString;
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn2;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tem (Telephone, Status, CreateDate)    VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", "telephone ");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", "status ");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", DateTime.Now);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    conn2.Close();
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

get the basics straight. DatetimeNow has NOTHING to do with SQL.

> My DateTime.Now value is like 28/02/2016 8:45:45 AM.

No. Your datetime.Now value is a double actually, internally. The STRING representation is what is generated by your UI Settings as you do not define a culture or a format string. YOu should do so if you want a specific format.

If your culture and the server's culture do not match up - naturally the datetime will not parse correctly.

This is why you should use parameters (and they avoid sql injection) and not deal with strings.

Comment: Thank you TomTom. As i said I'm a beginner so can you provide any sample or any link to help me to solve this.

Comment: @wajira000 you have all the samples needed in the marc_s answer. And do some research by yourself on Sql Injection and Parameterized queries